# ¿Como poner de color las celdas de Excel con phpExcel y Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

Estoy generando un Excel descuerdo a un formulario. Lo que quiero hacer es que las primeras 3 filas tengan un color amarillo, las otras tres que siguen estén sin color, las 3 que siguen de un color amarillo y así sucesivamente. No se si es posible hacer eso. Me podrian ayudar por favor, no tengo idea de como hacerlo.  Tal vez con una condicion, no se si sea una mejor idea al hacer eso, soy nuevo en esto y pido ayuda, muchas gracias

Esta es mi función donde genero el Excel:

```
 if($tipo_cpe == 'asiento') {
            $mes = $_GET['mes'];
            $ano = $_GET['ano'];
            $tipo = $_GET['doc'];

            require(APPPATH . 'third_party/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
            require(APPPATH . 'third_party/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php');
            $excel = new PHPExcel();
            $excel->getProperties()->setCreator("Escienza");
            $excel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("");
            $excel->getProperties()->setTitle("Asiento " . $mes . "/" . $ano);
            $excel->getProperties()->setSubject("");
            $excel->getProperties()->setDescription("");
            $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        

            //FILA 1
           $from = "A1"; // or any value 
$to = "P1"; // or any value 
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("$from:$to")->getFont()->setBold(true);
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'FECHA DOCUMENTO');
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B1", "MES");
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("C1", "FTE");
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("D1", "CUENTA");
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("E1", "AUXILIAR-1");
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("F1", "AUXILIAR-2");
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("G1", "AUXILIAR-3");
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("H1", "VOUCHER");
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("I1", "TD");
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("J1", "NUMERO DOCUMENTO");
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("K1", "SOLES DEBE");
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("L1", "SOLES HABER");
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("M1", "DOLAR DEBE");
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("N1", "DOLAR HABER");
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("O1", "DESCRIPCION");
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("P1", "TIPO CAMBIO");
            
            $r = 4;
            if ($tipo == "FACTURA") {
                $data = $this->venta_model->getDataAsiento($mes, $ano);
                foreach ($data->result() as $row) {
                    $date = new DateTime($row->fecha);
                    $fecha = $date->format('d/m/Y');
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A' . $r, $fecha);
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B' . $r, $mes);
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C' . $r, 'V');
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D' . $r, '701111');
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E' . $r, $row->ruc);
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F' . $r, ' ');
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G' . $r, ' ');
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H' . $r, '');
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I' . $r, '01');
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J' . $r, $row->serie.'-'.$row->numero);
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('K' . $r, '0');
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L' . $r, $row->subtotal);
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M' . $r, '0');
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('N' . $r, $row->total / 3.31 / 1.18);
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('O' . $r, "VENTA DE CONBUSTIBLE");
                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('P' . $r, '3.31');
               
                    $r++;
                   
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como puedo poner de color filas con phpExcel?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/369291/como-puedo-poner-de-color-filas-con-phpexcel)