# ¿Como puedo poner de color filas con phpExcel?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

estoy generando un excel descuerdo a un formulario, al momento de descargarlo y abrirlo quiero que se me iluminen 3 filas si y 3 no, así sucesivamente  . Estoy tratando de hacerlo con un ciclo for, pero no llego a mi objetivo. Alguien me podría ayudar por favor.

Este es mi código para colorear las filas.

```
  $el = 100;

                    for ($i = 4; $i < $el; $i++) {
                    if ($i % 6 != 0 ) {
                      $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A' . $i . ':P' . $i)->applyFromArray(
                    array(
                        'fill' => array(
                    'type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                    'color' => array('argb' => 'FFCCFFCC')
                ),
            )
        );
    }
}
```

El objetivo es llegar a esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en la condición `$i % 6 != 0`.

Para entender como corregir esta condición es necesario saber cuales son los posibles resultados de `$i % 6`.
Estos son: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

Luego necesitamos determinar cuales son las filas que necesitamos pintar utilizando dichos resultados.
Estas son: `3, 4, 5`

**Pero!** la numeración de las filas empieza en `1`, es decir, las filas `4, 5, 6`.
Esto quiere decir que necesitamos pintar las filas cuya numeración sean:

```
(($i % 6) + 1) > 3
```

#### Solución:

```
$el = 100;
for ($i = 4; $i < $el; $i++) {
    if ((($i % 6) + 1) > 3) {
        $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A' . $i . ':P' . $i)->applyFromArray(
            array(
                'fill' => array(
                    'type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                   'color' => array('argb' => 'FFCCFFCC')
                ),
            )
        );
    }
}
```